# Jest mock is always undefined within a mocked callback?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, jestjs

I am trying to mock a callback in jest using typescript.
However, despite my mock clearly being defined, on test execution it is somehow always undefined & therefore my code under test ends up using an undefined parameter being passed in & the tests fail.

```js
import { MetricsLogger } from 'aws-embedded-metrics';
import { SQSEvent, SQSRecord } from 'aws-lambda';

import { handle } from '../../src/handler';

export const mockedLogger = {
  setNamespace: jest.fn(() => mockedLogger),
  setProperty: jest.fn(() => mockedLogger),
  createMetricsLogger: jest.fn(),
} as Partial<MetricsLogger> as MetricsLogger;

jest.mock('aws-embedded-metrics', () => ({
  MetricsLogger: jest.fn(() => mockedLogger),
  metricScope: jest.fn((callback) => callback(mockedLogger)),
  createMetricsLogger: jest.fn(() => mockedLogger),
}));
```

The error that I get is:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNamespace')

The code under test is:

```
metricsLogger
        .setNamespace(process.env.NAMESPACE)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How are `MetricsLogger` and `metricsLogger` related?  Can you re-check variable initialization code for `metricsLogger`